# File Element size is 0 in Clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I am getting element size is 0 even though it has code.How to troubleshoot this error ?

[image]

Comment: It seems like "loaded but missing" error. What do you get on tooltip when you hover on the "???" icon? What do you get if you try "cleartool ls" from command-line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. If, when you hover over the "???" icon, you get "loaded but missing", then you shall follow instructions in

   http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21258149.
2. If the tooltip is "checked out but removed", then you shall simply undo the checkout. In that case there is no *Undo Checkout* option in the context menu, but you can use the *Undo Checkout* button in the menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that there is "no version selected" by the current view configuration. Tamir's suggestion of a cleartool ls is a good way to flush that issue out as it will be highlighted in the output.

Since you seem to be using ClearCase Explorer on Windows, does this file appear in the directory if you use **Windows** explorer? If it doesn't, "no version selected" moves up the list of possible causes.